# No se visualiza datos de interpolación en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interpolacion

Soy nuevo en Angular. Estoy intentando interpolar datos que vienen de un archivo JSON. Al agregar el pipe de JSON si es posible ver el objeto pero no se visualiza los valores del objeto con la interpolación, no se muestra ningún error, simplemente no se muestran.

archivo JSON

```js
{  
  "secciones":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "nombre":"Servicio Automotríz y Motos",
            "alt_img": "https://tsp.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/mechanic.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "anuncios":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "nombre": "cerrajeria autoalarmas",
            "nombre_imagen": "cerrajeria-autoalarmas",
            "id_seccion": 1,
            "descripcion": "el mejor sevicio de cerajeria para tu casa, negocio o automovil",
            "telefono": "2223654356",
            "direccion": "calle Pablo Sidar Sur #76, Barrio de San Bartolome",
            "valoracion": 4,
            "visitas": 23
        }
       
    ]
}
```

Este es el servicio que obtiene los datos del JSON

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, catchError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Seccion } from '../interfaces/seccion.interface';
import { environments } from 'src/environments/environments';
import { Anuncio } from '../interfaces/anuncio.interface';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DirectorioService {

  private baseUrl: string = environments.baseUrl;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  
     
  getAnuncioById(id: string):Observable<Anuncio|undefined>
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<Anuncio>(`${this.baseUrl}/anuncios?id=${id}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError (error => of(undefined))
    );
  }

}
```

Código del componente

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DirectorioService } from '../../services/directorio.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { Anuncio } from '../../interfaces/anuncio.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'pagina-anuncio',
  templateUrl: './pagina-anuncio.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class PaginaAnuncioComponent implements OnInit{
  
  
  public anuncioV?: Anuncio;

  constructor(
    private directorioService: DirectorioService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router 
  ){}
  

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.params 
    .pipe(
      switchMap(({id}) => this.directorioService.getAnuncioById(id)),
    )
    .subscribe (anuncio => {
      if(!anuncio) {
        return this.router.navigate(['/directorio']);
      }
      else{

        return this.anuncioV = anuncio;
      }             
    }      
    )
  }


}
```

Interfaz Anuncio

```js
export interface Anuncio {
    id:            number;
    nombre:        string;
    nombre_imagen: string;
    id_seccion:    number;
    descripcion:   string;
    telefono:      string;
    direccion:     string;
    valoracion:    number;
    visitas:       number;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="anuncioV; else divLoading " class="grid">
   
    
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title> {{anuncioV.nombre}} </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>{{anuncioV.telefono}}</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>

    </mat-card>
 
   

</div>

{{anuncioV | json}}
```

Al ejecutar y visualizar la pagina solo se muestra el objeto pasado con el pipe JSON pero no los valores los cuales deberían aparecer en la marca en rojo de la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esperando contar con su apoyo quedo atento, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es que no estás recibiendo un objeto. Estás recibiendo un Array. Puedes solventarlo refiriendote a la posición [0] del Array

```
this.anuncioV = anuncio[0];
return this.anuncioV
```

Si haces esto, ten en cuenta que tienes también que modificar el tipado de anuncio en tu servicio y en vez de referirte al interface "Anuncio", tendrás que hacerlo a un Array de anuncios "Anuncio[]"

```
 getAnuncioById(id: string):Observable<Anuncio[]|undefined>
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<Anuncio[]>...
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.